# A couple of issues with JSHint: 'is defined but never used' and 'is not defined'

Tags: javascript, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

I have this application pretty modular and as such, JSHint is giving me the `'x' is defined but never used` error.

My setup goes like this:

**app/assets/scripts/bootstrap.js:** `var x = 5;`

**app/assets/scripts/kickstart.js:** `console.log(x);`

And here's the output I get from JSHint:

```
app/assets/scripts/bootstrap.js
  line 1  col 6   'x' is defined but never used.

app/assets/scripts/kickstart.js
  line 1  col 13  'x' is not defined.

2 problems
```

I know I could us something like `/* exported x */` but would be really cumbersome if I have lots of variables like this.

Is there anyway to solve these 2 issues without disabling their specific options? Because they could come in handy in other, more important, situations.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this at the top of the file.

```
/*jshint unused: false, undef:false */
```

Notice that options can be applied to specific scopes. This works for `unused`, but apparently not for `undef`.

```
(function () {
  /*jshint unused: false */

  // Stuff
}());
```

Comment: `Is there anyway to solve these 2 issues without disabling their specific options` - This is from the question :)

Comment: @thefourtheye That's why I've added the part about scope options.

Comment: That doesn't really help much, I would have to add a similar comment to a bunch of files. That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral You can also have a JSON configuration file in a folder. In that case the options will be applied to all files in that folder

Comment: Won't that apply a global configuration to the folder?

Comment: @RicardoAmaral Yes. But you can have several folders.

Comment: I'm not going to restructure my folder structure to work around an issue like this, that's bad design and it means something is broken.